# How to update query string and reload Page on DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, query-string

have Dropdownlist which have languages  how to reload page each time change selected item from dropdown ?

```
  protected void DDLLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("Language") == false )
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl + "?Language=" + DDLLanguages.SelectedValue);
            }
            else
            {
             //i need to update the quesry string here 

            }

        }
```

Comment: Try to use DDLLanguages.SelectedItem.Text, or DDLLanguages.SelectedValue.ToString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void DDLLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("Language") == false )
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl + "?Language=" + DDLLanguages.SelectedValue);
            }
            else
            {
             //i need to update the quesry string here 
   Response.Redirect(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)+ "?Language=" + DDLLanguages.SelectedValue);

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer wipes out any existing query string values.

```
// parse url into UriBuilder //
var uri = new UriBuilder(Request.RawUrl);

// parse query part of url into a NameValueCollection //
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

// update/create "Language" entry in the NameValueCollection //
query["Language"] = DDLLanguages.SelectedValue;

// put updated NameValueCollection back into uri querystring //
uri.Query = query.ToString();

// redirect page to updated uri //
Response.Redirect(uri.ToString());
```

Comment: Will this add the `"Language"` parameter if it does not exist?

Comment: Yes it will add the key if not present. The query string object inherits from NameValueCollection which has this behavior.